# Cannot check a checkbox control using Selenium with C#

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to check a simple `input type=checkbox` using Selenium with C#, this is the HTML code I'm using:

```
<div _ngcontent-c5="" class="check-item">
    <input _ngcontent-c5="" class="custom ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="captcha" type="checkbox">
    <label _ngcontent-c5="" for="captcha" translate="">Text</label>
</div>
```

I've tried almost all possible approaches like `XPath`, `ID`, `Class` name with no success, this seems to be an Angular label or something like that
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `By.CssSelector("[for='captcha']");`?  This is a css selector for labels that point to an input with an id.

Comment: It does not work, it seems im dealing with a pseudelement here because im seeing ::before after the label